# Simulating Samsung Note 10 OS on Linux?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, android, qemu, android-studio

I am looking for a way to not have bioluminescent applications from my bank and the government on my private phone, but they are still required nowadays for anything from shopping to travel to whatever normal things you want to do.

So far I have been trying to simulate android in QEMU or VirtualBox and install my bank app there and use it, but it fails due to the lack of a safetynet API.

That creates the question. Is it possible to take the OS of a modern phone like a Samsung note 10 and simulate it in e.g. docker, QEMU or VirtualBox?

If no, what is stopping a `tar.md5` with images from running on a virtual machine?

Comment: what's a `bioluminescent application`?

Comment: “If no, what is stopping a tar.md5 with images from running on a virtual machine?” What the heck does that mean?

Comment: `tar.md5` is a hash of file and contain only one not so long string.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Can a `tar.md5` “…with images from running on a virtual machine?” This all sounds like gibberish.

Comment: Sure it's possible. Also, the app will detect it and refuse to run. Been there, done that. These apps even fail on exotic actual Android devices.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean opaque phosphorescent applications?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 From what I've seen Samsung firmware files are distributed as "tar.md5" files even though they are actually just tar files. The md5 seems them trying to imply they are signed (you can upload modified tar files but these will show the OS as unsafe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short No.

It is likely possible you can emulate the phone OS, but almost all modern phones have some kind of "secure enclave" which is hardware designed to thwart copying or emulation and which will be used by banking apps to ensure the device has not been backdoored.